# Equation of state for a radiation fluid

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics

Can anyone give me (point me to a reference of) a derivation of the equation of state for a radiation fluid:

pressure = energy/3

Much thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node90.html).

Comment: I see, it's a question of how collimated vs incoherent/uniform it is. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually looking for something that is citable in a research paper; I know it's essentially public domain at this point, but any citable reference would be appreciated.

Comment: @juacala A standard reference for such things is Weinberg's *Gravitation and Cosmology*. (It should also be in the newer *Cosmology*.)

Comment: Rybicki & Lightman.